# Horizontally concatenating periodically

Tags: files, cron, paste

I have 2 files namely f1 and f2. File f1 keeps getting new output periodically in the form

```
$cat f1
a
b
c
```

After "x" seconds

```
$cat f1
e
f
g
```

After "2x" seconds

```
$cat f1
    h
    i
    j
```

and so on.

I want to horizontally concatenate all the outputs in f1 in to a new file f2
which after "2x" seconds will have the output and it will continue in this fashion

```
$cat f2
a  e  h
b  f  i
c  g  j
```

How can I achieve this in linux using "paste" and crontab?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't -- `cron` is not accurate enough for that.

Instead I would suggest replacing f1 with a named pipe, attaching a reader process to that named pipe. That process would read for exactly `x` seconds, copying what is read into a file with a predictable, sequentially incrementing name. You could then use `cron` to periodically paste any such files together into `f2`, removing the ones you have already processed.